# Hex Conversion Error from Web Service Form call

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, web, hex

I'm receiving an error which looks like it is due to an error using hexidecimal inputs in a uint field.  It occurs on both versions of the web service I'm working on.

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert 0x2 to System.UInt32.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

However, my coworker says that it works for him on a previous version of the web service I have, when he calls it using C++, but it doesn't work on the current version I'm working on.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to cast the value? AKA the line that is raising the error.

Comment: are you accidentally putthe 0x2 in quotes when you don't mean too?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using something like this in your code? If not, try to implement this (replace "CF01" with your input value):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32("CF01", 16);
```

Edit:

For the particular case with the 0x prefix:

```
public int32 GetInt32FromHex(string h) {
    h = h.substring(2, (h.length - 2));
    return convert.ToInt32(h, 16);
}
```

Comment: I have a program that parses a lot of hex strings.  This is the method I use, and, it broke the first time because I was capturing the 0x as part of the string.

Comment: Yeah, you need to chop that that one. You can use .Substring(2, s.length-2) before passing it to the converter.

Comment: I updated the answer. Of course, you probably want to implement a check first of h before passing it for convertion.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting error because it seems like the Parse method of `UInt32` is only able to parse numbers of the form `[ws][sign]digits[ws]` per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b23e5abt.aspx).  There is a version of the method that can take `NumberStyles` flags see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41810tes.aspx).  One of the values of this is `AllowHexSpecifier` which you'd think would allow the 0x.  However if you read the documentation for both the Parse method and the [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) unable to handle the 0x format at all.  If you look at the  it says:

> If s is the string representation of a hexadecimal number, it cannot be preceded by any decoration (such as 0x or &h) that differentiates it as a hexadecimal number. This causes the conversion to fail.

The AllowHexSpecifier makes it so that only numbers of the form `[ws]hexdigits[ws]`

It seems like you are going to have to get rid of the leading 0x before parsing or use another method of parsing.

One way to do that, especially if there is a leading 0x is to do the following:

```
var value = UInt32.Parse( "0x2".TrimStart('0').TrimStart('x'));
```

You will have to be careful here to do checking to make sure you have the proper base though and you may need to use the `NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` to parse correctly.